Why is "dict[int, int]" incompatible with "dict[int, int | str]"?
import typing

a: dict[int, int] = {}
b: dict[int, int | str] = a
c: typing.Mapping[int, int | str] = a
d: typing.Mapping[int | str, int] = a

Pylance reports an error for b: dict[int, int | str] = a:
Expression of type "dict[int, int]" is incompatible with declared type "dict[int, int | str]"
  "dict[int, int]" is incompatible with "dict[int, int | str]"
    Type parameter "_VT@dict" is invariant, but "int" is not the same as "int | str"
    Consider switching from "dict" to "Mapping" which is covariant in the value type

But c: typing.Mapping[int, int | str] = a is OK.
Additionally, d: typing.Mapping[int | str, int] = a also gets an error:
Expression of type "dict[int, int]" is incompatible with declared type "Mapping[int | str, int]"
  "dict[int, int]" is incompatible with "Mapping[int | str, int]"
    Type parameter "_KT@Mapping" is invariant, but "int" is not the same as "int | str"

Why are these types hint incompatible?
If a function declares a parameter of type dict[int, int | str], how can I pass a dict[int, int] object as its parameter?

See Wikipedia for why array-likes should be invariant: Covariance and contravariance § Arrays

Beside the point, but functions probably shouldn't declare parameters as dict in the first place, instead using Mapping or MutableMapping as required (read-only or read-write, respectively).

I found a great article about it: https://blog.daftcode.pl/covariance-contravariance-and-invariance-the-ultimate-python-guide-8fabc0c24278

Would-be duplicate: Why doesn't parameter type "Dict[str, Union[str, int]]" accept value of type "Dict[str, str]" (mypy).

dict type was designed to be completely invariant on key and value. Hence when you assign dict[int, int] to dict[int, int | str], you make the type system raise errors. [1]
Mapping type on the other hand wasn’t designed to be completely invariant but rather is invariant on key and covariant on value. Hence you can assign one Mapping type (dict[int, int]) to another (Mapping[int, int | str]) if they are both covariant on value. if they are invariant on key, you can assign them else you cannot. Hence when you assign dict[int, int] to Mapping[int | str, int], you make the type system raise errors. [2][3]
There is a good reason for the above design in the type system and I will give a few:
1. dict type is a concrete type so it will actually get used in a program.
2. Because of the above mentioned, it was designed the way it was to avoid things like this:
a: dict[int, int] = {}
b: dict[int, int | str] = a
b[0] = 0xDEADBEEF
b[1] = "Bull"
dicts are assigned by reference [4] hence any mutation to b is actually a mutation to a. So if one reads a as follows:
x: int = a[0]
assert isinstance(x, int)
y: int = a[1]
assert isinstance(y, int)
One gets unexpected results. x passes but y doesn’t. It then seems like the type system is contradicting itself. This can cause worse problems in a program.
For posterity, to correctly type a dictionary in Python, use Mapping type to denote a readonly dictionary and use MutableMapping type to denote a read-write dictionary.

[1] Of course Python’s type system doesn’t influence program’s running behaviour but at least linters have some use of this.
[2] dict type is a Mapping type but Mapping type is not a dict type.
[3] Keep in mind that the ordering of types is important in type theory.
[4] All variable names in Python are references to values.

One nit: there is nothing special about dicts with regard to assignment. All values are assigned "by reference" (though the sense is different from how languages like C++ would consider a reference).

@chepner it by values you mean Containers? I can’t think of a contradiction. But primitives are copied in Python are they?

No. Python doesn't really have primitives. Everything is a Python object that has, in addition to whatever data it represents, additional metadata like a reference to its class object, a reference count, etc. A Python variable is just a name that refers to some object.

Wow I never knew this. Thanks for this information. I’ll look into it in more detail.

https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html is a good discussion and reference.

That is a beautiful article @chepner. Did you write it? It is so good. It is beginner friendly and can take one from novice to intermediate in a single read. Thanks once again.

No, I'm not Ned Batchelder :)

This code may seem correct on first sight if you think of only reading from the dicts:
a: dict[int, int] = {}
b: dict[int, int | str] = a

However, if you ever write to them, you can see how it would be wrong to allow that:
b[1] = "x"
assert isinstance(a[1], int)  # fails

The difference with Mapping type is that it does not support modifications.
(Chukwujiobi's answer explains it well in legal language, if you want a more precise explanation)

But this is OK:
e: typing.MutableMapping[int, typing.Any] = a

@keakon using typing.Any tells the type system to exempt that from type checks.

@ChukwujiobiCanon Then I can set e[1] = '1' which breaks the declared type of a.

@keakon: Any is shorthand for "pretend I inserted casts everywhere, and don't complain if that makes no sense."

in short: never use Any, unless you're looking for trouble
